# Laravel: Load relationships and specific columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables `User` and `Car`. One user may have a car.

I have a relation set like this:

```
public function car()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Car');
}
```

I want to fetch the users with a car, but only select the `name` of the user and the `color` of the car.

If I try

```
App\User::with('car:color')->select('name')->first()->toArray();
```

then I do not get the car color. That is the result:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Max Mustermann"
    "car" => []
  ]
]
```

Is it possible to only get the name of the user and the color of the car?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because the `User` Table has no `color` Column. You have to access the relation to get the color.

```
$user = User::has('car')->first();

print $user->car->color;
```

AFAIK you won't be able to fetch just the two fields with Eloquent Relations. One way to achieve this would be using Query Builder:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('cars', 'users.id', '=', 'cars.user_id')
    ->select('users.name', 'cars.color')
    ->get();
```

Comment: This will only fetch first row from user table.

Comment: I understand that you approach works, but this returns all fiends of the user. I only want my user object to have 2 attributes, in this case only `$user->name` and `$user->car->color` no need to load all the other fields from the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
User :: Select("*")->with("car")->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, your approach works. But is there a query so that the returned user object only has 2 attributes, in this case only `$user->name` and `$user->car->color`? There is  no need for my application to load all the other fields from the two tables. When I wrote raw SQL commands, I never used `SELECT * FROM` ... to gain speed

Comment: @Adam, I am glad that you got a solution with help of my answer, it will be good if you accept this answer and vote it up. And for your concern about speed, I would say, this is ORM, it will not take time as a normal query takes to fetch with `select * from table` so don't worry. This won't make any huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way.

```
$users = User::with('car.color')->select('name')->get();
```

and then you can display them as:

```
foreach($users as $user){
     echo $user->name . " owns a " . $user->car->color . " car.";
}
```

Comment: If I do that then `$user->car-color` is null